# bootstrap3 and twitter typeahead integration

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, typeahead, typeahead.js, mobile-devices

I am trying to integrate twitter-typeahead with bootstrap3.
I want to use a typeahead inside a navbar.

The problem appears only when navbar is collapsed and only in mobile devices (issue at least in iPhone safari and BB10 browser), and it is the following:

The typeahead dropdown appears under the rest of the navbar content:

**BlackBerry10 browser**

[image: screenshoot of the problem]

**Safari on iPhone**

[image: screenshoot of the problem]

I tried tweaking z-index and position:

```
.twitter-typeahead .tt-dropdown-menu {
     position: absolute !important; 
     z-index:9999 !important;
}
```

I have replicated the issue here:

http://jsfiddle.net/zZpQg/3/

Why is this happening only in mobile small devices?
How can I get the typeahead dropdown to appear on top of the rest of the links?

KindRegards

Comment: +1 for an excellent composed question.

Comment: I am having a similar problem, which can be reproduced on safari on my mac.

Answer (score 1):

I also added

```
.tt-query {
     backgroud-color: #fff !important; 
}
```

for the input type.

Comment: Thanks, but it's not a question of dropdown transparence. Dropdown links are unclickable because they get rendered under normal navbar links, in a deeper layer.